# Instagram permission (relationships) is only granted to apps that enable brands and advertisers

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

In my website, I have Instagram **follow button** in shopping cart page. If the user **follow** us, we will give them promotion code for Offer. But it requires **relationship permission** in scope(API url).

```
var url = https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id......&scope=relationships;
```

After Submission I got this response,
Permission (relationships) :
This permission (relationships) is only granted to apps that **enable brands and advertisers to manage their followers**. We do not grant access to apps that do not fall into these categories.

I don't know why they are rejecting my app. I have choosed **'My product helps brands and advertisers understand, manage their audience and media rights'** option. Also gave video url and etc. but no use. Please anyone guide me to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your app functionality of exchanging follow for promo code is not meeting the usecase "enable brands and advertisers to manage their followers"